# HTML5 video duration varies across browsers when the start time is negative

Tags: javascript, html, video, ffmpeg

I'm working on a web video editor and the duration for videos with negative start time varies across browsers. Here's the ffmpeg output:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mp4

ffmpeg version 3.3.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.3.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 58.100 / 55. 58.100
  libavcodec     57. 89.100 / 57. 89.100
  libavformat    57. 71.100 / 57. 71.100
  libavdevice    57.  6.100 / 57.  6.100
  libavfilter     6. 82.100 /  6. 82.100
  libavresample   3.  5.  0 /  3.  5.  0
  libswscale      4.  6.100 /  4.  6.100
  libswresample   2.  7.100 /  2.  7.100
  libpostproc    54.  5.100 / 54.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/filipebrandao/Downloads/mars1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2017-08-24T19:43:26.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:03.25, start: -0.001610, bitrate: 2037 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x534 [SAR 1:1 DAR 640:267], 1075 kb/s, 23.91 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-08-24T19:43:26.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 126 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-08-24T19:43:26.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
At least one output file must be specified
```

The important bit from above is the negative start time:

```
Duration: 00:00:03.25, start: -0.001610, bitrate: 2037 kb/s
```

When I play this video in Chrome and Firefox, both browsers report a duration of 5.72 secs. When I use Safari, the browser reports a duration of 3.24 sec.

Do you know of a way of having consistent duration and start time values across browsers?

Comment: If "don't have videos with a negative start time" is an option, check the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219997/ffmpeg-is-setting-start-time-to-a-negative-value-on-output)

Comment: thanks @James - I'm aware that I can transcode the video with ffmpeg and that would solve the issue, but I'm wondering if there's a way to ignore the negative values on the browser without changing the video

Comment: There are no options in the browser to change how it reads an mp4 file.